# Using QT, how to call function once after a certain interval, even if more calls may occur?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am having a hard time wording this question even though I don't think its that complicated.

I want to do something simalar to `QTimer::singleshot()` but I want it to still only call the SLOT once even if `QTimer::singleshot()` is called multiple times before it fires.

Comment: Why can't you just disconnect the slot after the timer fires for the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
class MyObject
{

// ...
    QTimer* mTimer;
}

MyObject::MyObject()
{
    mTimer = new QTimer(this);
    mTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(mTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(doStuff()));
}

MyObject::startOrResetTimer()
{
   mTimer->start(1000);
}
```

Comment: +1 The key here is that if `singleShot` is true, the timer will be activated only once when `start()` is called.

Comment: Question is if you want to restart the timer if it is already running. Here, if startOrResetTimer is called every 900ms, the timer will be restarted all the time and never timeout.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld If you want that, add `if (!mTimer->isActive())` before `start()`.

Comment: Timmmm: Sure, just wanted to point out that one has to decide which behavior is wanted.

Comment: IMO unnecessarily more polluted than @simotek's answer

Comment: @fabian789: I don't believe simotek's answer actually does what the question wants. The documentation does not support his claim that calling `QTimer::singleShot(...)` twice will only trigger the slot once.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to call a slot once off a timer you could look at something like

`QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(MySlot()));`

Then your guaranteed it will only happen once.

To clarify, by calling the static version of this rather then calling it from a existing timer it will only happen once.

Comment: This is a very clean solution

Comment: This doesn't answer what the question asks, and the SLOT will still be called multiple times if you call it multiple times, just that all will fire at the end of slot.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works well for me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `singleShot()` static member function with **lambda** for this purpose easily:

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000, [=](){
    qDebug()<<"do something after 2000 msec...";
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Quick-and-dirty: use a boolean in your class and set it to true in the slot; ignore subsequent calls until the boolean is reset.

Comment: That is resource intensive if say the timer will call the function after days not seconds.

Comment: A single boolean is resource intensive??

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the code gets called hundreds of times per second, a day waiting could be a lot of time spent checking a bool. That's what @Zaid meant I think.

Comment: @zimano I think the overhead of the hundreds of calls is more to worry about. Anyway, we don't know anything about the rest of the code or even the reason for the single usage, so this is all speculation.