# How to call a function after every 15 seconds using QT

Tags: c++, qt

I know my question is similar to this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269766/using-qt-how-to-call-function-once-after-a-certain-interval-even-if-more-calls) but i cant find solution from there. Can anyone give a breif answer to my problem?

I have a function like this

```
void myWidget::showGPS()
{

/* This function will read data from text file
      that will continuouly change over time
           then process its data */

}
```

I want to call this function every 15-20 seconds without using Quick-and-dirty method of setting boolean to true .

Is there any way to implement this using 
QT signal and slot with timer or something like that

Comment: You can still use QTimer? just set your time interval to 15 seconds? and link your function with the timer through "connect"? (similar to the link you found.

Comment: Examples are on docs for QTimer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The method `showGPS()`, should be made a slot of `MyWidget` class.
Then on, its just a matter of using the `QTimer` class.

```
 QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), myWidget, SLOT(showGPS()));
    timer->start(15000); //time specified in ms
```

The above code will call showGPS(), every 15 seconds.
Since the call is periodic, you don't have to set the timer in one shot mode using the `setSingleShot()` method.

Edit:

This is a simple poc, to help you understand it..

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <qobject.h>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWidget()
    {
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showGPS()));
        timer->start(1000); //time specified in ms
    }

public slots:
    void showGPS()
    {
        qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

private:
    QTimer *timer;
};


int main(int argc, char **args)
 {
    QApplication app(argc,args);
    MyWidget myWidget;


    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While you can use QTimer for checking file changes, in your case QFileWatcher might be better solution.

Comment: Depending on the rate of updates of the file, you might want to rate limit the update. That in turn would probably again involve a `QTimer`.